# How to throw CAUSE on http request exception

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have the follow REST controller

```
import ...ApplicationUser
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sign-up")
class SignUpController: BaseController() {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping
    fun signUp(@RequestBody applicationUser: ApplicationUser) {
        applicationUser.password = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(applicationUser.password)
        applicationUserRepository.save(applicationUser)
    }
}
```

and model/entity

```
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
class ApplicationUser(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        var id: Long? = null,

        @Column(unique = true)
        var username: String? = null,

        var password: String? = null
) {
    @Column(unique = true)
    var email: String? = null

    ...
}
```

So, purposely I'm trying save an `user` with an existing `email` and naturally I get the follow throw

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-29T15:40:45.784+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/sign-up"
}
```

But this throw has a **CAUSE**, the cause is that (in portuguese, sorry lol)

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violação da restrição
>   UNIQUE KEY 'UK_cb61p28hanadv7k0nx1ec0n5l'. Não é possível inserir uma
>   chave duplicada no objeto 'dbo.application_user'. O valor de chave
>   duplicada é (admin@email.com).

So, how to send/put/join the cause to http's response exception? Something like this

```
{
    "timestamp": ...,
    "status": ...,
    "error": ...,
    "message": ...,
    "cause": "here is the cause of all problems",
    "path": ...
}
```

It's possible? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ControllerAdvice to handle these kind of exception.
You can configure it to catch any exception in the application and then return appropriate response code/message. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f)